# Are `equals()` and `contains()` included in string manipulation methods in java?

Tags: java, strings

Write a method called isSubstring which takes two string parameters & returns boolean value; true, only if string is substring of other. **Do not use any manipulation methods of the string other than length().**

Is this correct solution?

What's the other possible solution?

```
public static boolean isSubstring(String str1, String str2) {
    int len1 = str1.length();
    int len2 = str2.length();
    if (len1 < len2) {
       return str2.contains(str1); 
    } else if (len1 == len2) {
       return str1.equals(str2);
    } else {
      return str1.contains(str2);
    }
}
```

Comment: I doubt this is correct because you are using `contains` and `equals`, both of which are string methods.

Comment: The instructions seem to imply that using `contains()` and `equals()` is "cheating".

Comment: @200_success So whats the other possible solution? Please help.

Comment: I think that the intention of the exercise is to analyze the strings the hard way — character by character.

Answer (score 1):

I don't follow the question exactly. Are you seeing if either string is a substring of the other, or does it have to be that `str1` is a substring of `str2`? Basing off your current logic, I'm assuming the first case.

I'm also assuming that, if the strings are equal, they're considered substrings of each other.

### Non-contiguous Substring

You can go the old-fashioned way and use character-by-character comparison:

```
public class IsSubstring {
    private static boolean isSubstringHelper(String sub_str, String longer_str) {
        int i, j;
        // we can break early if substring length is reached before end of longer string
        for(i = 0, j = 0; i < longer_str.length() && j < sub_str.length(); ++i) {
            // move through substring if we found a character match
            if(sub_str.charAt(j) == longer_str.charAt(i)) {
                j++;
            }
        }

        // we found the substring only if we reached end of substring length
        return (j == sub_str.length());
    }

    public static boolean isSubstring(String str1, String str2) {
        // use helper function for getting substring (less code to type this way)
        if(str1.length() > str2.length()) {
            return isSubstringHelper(str2, str1);
        }
        else {
            return isSubstringHelper(str1, str2);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(isSubstring("abc", "abcd"));      // true
        System.out.println(isSubstring("abcd", "ddabscd"));  // true
        System.out.println(isSubstring("abc", "abc"));       // true
        System.out.println(isSubstring("abc", "abd"));       // false
        System.out.println(isSubstring("abd", "abc"));       // false
    }
}
```

### Contiguous Substring

All you need to do is modify the above code so that the body of the for loop (within `isSubstringHelper`) reads out as:

```
if(sub_str.charAt(j) == longer_str.charAt(i)) {
    j++;
}
else {
    // reset counter since contiguous substring not found
    j = 0;
}
```

Hopefully the above helps.

Answer (score -1):

I think, this variant is better, because `equals` and `contains` the same when `len1 == len2`

```
public static boolean isSubstring(String str1, String str2) {
    if (str1.length() > str2.length()) {
       return str1.contains(str2); 
    } else {
      return str2.contains(str1);
    }
}
```